# To formally ask/thank somebody: "By virtue of this email/letter"

Tags: correspondence

When I want to formally ask/express your idea to somebody/an organization through email/letter, is the following phrase OK?

"...
By virtue of this email, I request your organization for X.
By virtue of this email, I express my dissatisfaction with your service.
By virtue of this email, I draw it to your attention that blah blah. "

Comment: Looks like purple prose to me.

Comment: Not sure what the point of adding that phrase is, even if it's formal. What is your concern with simply saying "I request your organization for X", etc., without "by virtue of this email"?

Comment: Perhaps to imply the importance of my email; or to somehow emphasize the importance if my request...

Comment: *By virtue of* means *because of, on account of*. You've used it to mean *by means of, with, per*.

Comment: English Language Learners folks

Answer (score 2):

Linguistics refers to an element of pragmatics referred to as a "speech act."  Speech acts perform some function other than the mere communication of information.  An example might be an oath of office, or some other ceremony, in which a pronouncement is made to effect some change.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act.)  So it's understandable that a writer might wish to *imitate speech* in writing and to use expressions, such as the one's in the OP's question, to make the letter feel "official" or to make it seem like it's accomplishing something.

However, I agree with beeftendon's comment that "by virtue of" is not needed in writing.  Not only is it unnecessary, it might be perceived as amateurish.  Children, as early as elementary school, are taught to "introduce the subject" they are going to write about.  They often do this with trite, unimaginative phrases such as "I'm going to tell you about..." or "The purpose of this paper is to...." This is one of the things that gives their writing an amateurish (if not endearing) feel.

But a written document is not speech.  It doesn't need the flowery wording (such as "by the power vested in me..." or "by virture of...") that speech acts tend to use.  Using them in writing can cause the letter to sound amateurish in the same way that "I'm going to tell you about" can come across as child-like.

If the purpose of the letter is to accomplish something (such as request something from an organization), then just request it:

- "Would your organization be able to...?"
- "What would be required for your organization to...?"

If the purpose of the letter is to express dissatisfaction or satisfaction, but not necessarily to generate a specific response, then just express what you want to get across:

- "I was so happy to see that..."
- "Your product failed 30 minutes after I started to use it..."

I'm not suggesting the example sentences above need to *start* the letter.  You may still need to set the scene or establish context before getting to the point.  They were only meant to show that "by virtue of" or similar phrases aren't needed, they may be perceived as child-like or pompous, and the letter may end up being taken *less* seriously.